# Return multiple Google search results in same query

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to search for more than one topic at a time in Google?

For example, I wish to look for speeches for President Obama, President Bush, and President Clinton and didn't want to do a search for presidential speeches but wanted three separate search results.

Another example is if you want a photo of a chair, Tiger Woods, and a walker.

Any way to get a response for each of these separately without having to search three different times?

Comment: What search engine is this?

Comment: You can open up tabs in your browser and search each one.  In chrome you can just type your search into the address bar to search so it would be cntl+t then type search, repeat to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `President (Obama|Bush|Clinton)`, but depending on popularity of each, you may still have to do separate searches. For example, Tiger Woods will overwhelm the search results in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

For the image search:

[chair OR "tiger woods" OR walker](http://www.google.com/images?q=chair+OR+%22tiger+woods%22+OR+walker)

For the presidential speeches search you type: [speeches obama OR clinton OR bush](http://www.google.com/search?q=speeches&as_epq=&as_oq=obama+clinton+bush) into Google.

Comment: I think `speeches (obama|clinton|bush)` would work better. The grouping tells Google that `speeches` should be included no matter what.

Comment: The query I posted does the same thing.